# Make PHP on a Puphpet/Vagrant box use specific sub version e.g. 7.0.4 vs 7.0.5

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrantfile, puphpet, vagrant-provision

Using [puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) a typical config.yaml php section might look like this:

```
php:
install: '1'
settings:
    version: '70'
modules:
    php:
        - ioncube-loader
```

I have lots of other PHP modules installed but its ioncube I'm having issues with.

Up until just earlier, this was provisioning with PHP 7.0.4, which seemed to have a yum package for Ioncube loader.

I just had to rerun `vagrant provision` and now all of a sudden I appear to be on PHP 7.0.5.

Not much of a bother normally, except now I get issues with dependencies for ioncube (ioncube loader is crucial to run some encrypted 3rd party code I need).

My question is: **Is it possible to lock php down to 7.0.4?**

`version: '704'` doesn't work.

Also just to check I've understood the error message correctly:

```
Error: Package: php-ioncube-loader-5.1.2-1.el6.remi.5.4.x86_64 (remi)
       Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
       Installed: php-common-7.0.5-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php70)
           php(api) = 20151012-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.45-5.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Available: php-common-5.4.45-7.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
       Available: php-common-7.0.4-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           php(api) = 20151012-64
       Available: php55u-common-5.5.33-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 (ius)
           php(api) = 20121113-64
       Available: php56u-common-5.6.19-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 (ius)
           php(api) = 20131106-64
       Available: php70u-common-7.0.4-1.ius.centos6.x86_64 (ius)
           php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64
```

Other suggestions welcome, I just need ioncube loader working on this 1 project, am I right here? It looks like its available for every version of php except the one that's magically appeared on mine since the last provision. It's totally possible I'm barking up the wrong tree....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author of PuPHPet here.

Unfortunately subversions are not supported (`7.0.x`), only major versions (`7.0`).

This is due to the absolutely insane way each distro and even each PHP version is so different to the other in regards to INI locations and module directories. It's ridiculous.

What *could* easily be added is support for `ensure` field to the YAML file that you could pass your specific version to. Mind opening a ticket on my github tracker to enable this?

Comment: Thanks Juan for the update but you're using example42 php module ? This one should support php subversion or am I mistaken ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I'm using it but have built extensively on top of it to fit puphpet's needs. I sincerely wish PHP installation was easier.

Comment: Can imagine, you did a great work with puphpet (even if I'm not using it myself)

Comment: Done: https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2254 and yes I agree with @FrédéricHenri puphpet is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

hum

> `version: '704'` doesn't work

should be

```
settings:
    version: '7.0.4'
```

Comment: Nope, first thing I tried... `vagrant provision` gives "Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Unrecognized PHP version at..."

Comment: Ok would check the puphpet code as the php module comes from example42 and its possible to déclaré version as 7.0.4 or 7.0.5

Comment: yep... thanks, awaiting response from the puphpet people, would be surprised if it's not possible somehow! Have I interpreted the error correctly? That the ioncube module is dependent on something that's not available for 7.0.5?

Answer (score 0):

ioncube loader is not yet compatible with PHP 7, whatever version you install (7.0.4 or 7.0.5).

See the [Compatibility list](http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status)

Also see: [upstream forum thread](http://forum.ioncube.com/viewtopic.php?t=4287)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I did think this, however, I seem to have had it working very briefly on 7.0.4, which was total fluke and surprised me... but as soon as `vagrant provision` bumped to 7.0.5 I got the issue again.

Nevertheless, ioncube loader was just an example, my real question is whether it is possible to use puphpet's config.yaml to lock php down to a specific sub version (to the third decimal place, if that makes sense) and what the syntax would be. I'd like to have that control if possible.